# Eclipse Mars 2 SmartHome (OOMPH) - Cannot build SmartHome projects

Tags: eclipse, p2, oomph

I've been struggling with the SmartHome SDK of the Eclipse project.
I've followed the instructions in http://www.eclipse.org/smarthome/documentation/development/ide.html but I'm still running into issues.

When I try to perform the update tasks for re-building the project, I get this error log:

> Executing manual tasks Product
>   org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.latest.released Project
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.master Project
>   org.eclipse.equinox.framework.master Project
>   org.eclipse.equinox.bundles.master Project
>   org.eclipse.smarthome.core.master Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup
>   1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194, branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.git 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.jdt 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.launching 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projects 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Bundle
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.workingsets 1.3.0.v20160213-0953, build=2194,
>   branch=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913,
>   commit=c991531eaee52798fcea97b4b75db38b5d95e913 Performing P2 Director
>   (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Mars)) Offline = true Mirrors = true
>   Resolving 34 requirements from 8 repositories to D:\Programs\Eclipse -
>   Java only\eclipse Requirement
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group [2.6.0,2.7.0) Requirement
>   org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group [2.6.0,2.7.0) Requirement
>   org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.sdk.feature.group [2.6.0,2.7.0)
>   Requirement org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.sdk.feature.group
>   [2.6.0,2.7.0) Requirement org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.feature.group
>   [1.3.2,1.4.0) Requirement org.eclipse.emf.mwe.sdk.feature.group
>   [1.3.2,1.4.0) Requirement
>   org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.pde.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group Requirement
>   epp.package.java [4.5.0,4.6.0) Requirement
>   org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.5.0,4.6.0) Requirement
>   org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.5.0,4.6.0) Requirement
>   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [3.11.0,3.12.0) Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.targlets.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.jdt.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.git.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.egit.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.workingsets.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projects.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.launching.feature.group Requirement
>   org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ee.feature.feature.group Repository
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-tycho/0.7.0/N/0.7.0.201309291400/
>   Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/
>   Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/milestones/
>   Repository http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/
>   Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars
>   Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201602261000
>   Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
>   Repository http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates Adding repository
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-tycho/0.7.0/N/0.7.0.201309291400/
>   Adding repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/
>   Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates Adding
>   repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/milestones/
>   Adding repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest Adding
>   repository http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/
>   Adding repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars Adding
>   repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201602261000
>   Refresh DSLD scripts Refresh DSLD scripts Synchronizing Resources...
>   Refresh DSLD scripts Synchronizing Resources... Calculating
>   requirements and dependencies. Refresh DSLD scripts Synchronizing
>   Resources... Searching for markers Process resource updates Preparing
>   to validate org.eclipse.smarthome.ui.paper Validation done Computing
>   prerequisite plan No software updates are available Performing
>   Preference
>   /instance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.codeComplete.argumentSuffixes
>   Performing Preference
>   /instance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.codeComplete.staticFinalFieldSuffixes
>   Performing Targlets (Eclipse Platform + Equinox Bundles + Equinox
>   Framework + Equinox P2 + Equinox Platform) Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/cbi/updates/license Offline = true Mirrors
>   = true Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update Adding repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/cbi/updates/license Calculating
>   requirements and dependencies. Cannot complete the request. 
>   Generating details. ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10053
>   Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.targlets.internal.core.TargletContainer.forceUpdate(TargletContainer.java:688)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.impl.TargletTaskImpl$4.run(TargletTaskImpl.java:974)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.runWithTargetPlatformService(TargetPlatformUtil.java:119)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.impl.TargletTaskImpl.perform(TargletTaskImpl.java:910)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3036)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2980)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4170)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4164)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4162)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2971)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2946)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2857)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:555)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:674)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)   ERROR:
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Software being installed:
>   artificial_root 1.0.0.v1457620774191

```
 ERROR:
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Missing requirement:
artificial_root 1.0.0.v1457620774191 requires
'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Took 10 seconds. There are failed tasks. Press Back to choose
different settings or Cancel to abort.
```

For your convience I've highlighted the last lines which is the main error.
Is there something I can do to solve this? it seems like a plugin is missing but I can't figure out where to find it..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved by removing OpenHab Eclipse entirely and re-install it via Eclipse Installer. You should make sure that you choose "Advanced mode" and choose "OpenHab Development" and "OpenHab addons 2" from the list.